# PHP Trying to get property of non-object

Tags: php, apple-push-notifications

I'm running an APNS PHP script and it's working fine but one file throws PHP errors and I want to know how I should fix it.

The following errors pop up:

```
/usr/bin/php -f /usr/share/nginx/www/processFeedback.php

<br/>Started processing FeedbackPHP Notice:  Trying to get property of non-object in /usr/share/nginx/www/processFeedback.php on line 46
PHP Warning:  stream_socket_client(): unable to connect to  (Failed to parse address "") in /usr/share/nginx/www/classes/Apns.php on line 66
PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: errstrn in /usr/share/nginx/www/classes/Apns.php on line 69
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message '<br/>Failed to connect 0 ' in /usr/share/nginx/www/classes/Apns.php:69
Stack trace:
#0 /usr/share/nginx/www/classes/Apns.php(49): Apns->connect()
#1 /usr/share/nginx/www/processFeedback.php(46): Apns->__construct(NULL, 'certificates/ck...', 'passwd')
#2 {main}
  thrown in /usr/share/nginx/www/classes/Apns.php on line 69
```

Line 46:

```
$apns = new apns($server->ServerUrl, $certificatePath, $certificate->Passphrase);
```

Line 66:

```
$this->stream = stream_socket_client($this->server, $err, $errstr, 60, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT, $ctx);
```

Line 69:

```
throw new Exception("<br/>Failed to connect $err $errstrn");
```

PHP file: https://github.com/bortuzar/PHP-Mysql---Apple-Push-Notification-Server/blob/master/processFeedback.php

DataService.php: https://github.com/bortuzar/PHP-Mysql---Apple-Push-Notification-Server/blob/master/classes/DataService.php

APNS.php: https://github.com/bortuzar/PHP-Mysql---Apple-Push-Notification-Server/blob/master/classes/Apns.php

I'm not a PHP expert so what am I missing?

Comment: Where did you define `$certificateFolder`? It's not in the code you show... Also - the error occurs in `line 46`. Clearly you are not showing all your code here - there _is_ no line 46 in the snippet you show. Can you either show all the code, or at least clarify which is line 46?

Comment: @Floris It's Inside the config.php file "//Certificate folder
$certificateFolder = 'certificates';"

Comment: @Floris You're right, updated my first post. Thanks..

Comment: Check if the value of `$this->server` is an actual address or just an empty string.

Comment: Line 66 uses `$errstr`, but 69 finds that `errstrn` is undefined. Could that be a typo?

Comment: Line 66: `$apns = new apns($server->ServerUrl, $certificatePath, $certificate->Passphrase);` gets a "no object" warning. This means either `$server` or `$certificate` have not been properly instantiated. Where did you define them?

Comment: It would be a good idea to add a simple debug statement to your code (right before line 66): `echo $server->ServerUrl, $certificatePath, $certificate->Passphrase` . I expect that the output will surprise you.

Comment: I'm not sure I find many definitions in the Apns.php file - I tried contacting the developer but he tells me that he quited the project, so no help either.. Server is defined in a MySQL DB as well as server.

Comment: What happens when you add the `echo`? Can you see the output?

Comment: Just spotted this in the stack trace: `#1 /usr/share/nginx/www/processFeedback.php(46): Apns->__construct(NULL, 'certificates/ck...', 'passwd') ` . This clearly shows that $server is NULL. What do you expect the ServerUrl to be? Maybe you could just enter that as a string in the line in question, like so: `$apns = new apns('myServerUrl', $certificatePath, $certificate->Passphrase)`

Comment: Thanks, Indeed you are right. I added this and the script runs looking for the next bug now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just spotted this in the stack trace:

```
#1 /usr/share/nginx/www/processFeedback.php(46): Apns->__construct(NULL, 'certificates/ck...', 'passwd') .
```

This clearly shows that $server is NULL. What do you expect the ServerUrl to be? Maybe you could just enter that as a string in the line in question, like so:

```
$apns = new apns('myServerUrl', $certificatePath, $certificate->Passphrase)
```

Comment: Posted this as an "answer" so we can fix it from here, since you indicated this was at least a partial solution.

Comment: You were right about this, however the connection seems to be working now but the server connects without using a certificate, at least that's how it looks because when I remove the certificate the same output will come up. Not sure why tough it gives me no errors at all.

Comment: Accepted this for now, posted a new question regarding the next bug here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14612573/php-not-using-ssl-certificate thanks for your help!